# Can't get mysql_query to return any values that exist in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following snippet:

```
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
$sql = "SELECT FROM ec_opps WHERE id=" . $_GET["UPDATE"];
$item = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
print_r($item);
```

To try and retrieve data based on the UPDATE value. This value prints to the page accurately, and I know the IDs I'm requesting exist in the database. The print_r($item) function returns no result, not even an empty array, so I'm confused as to where I'm going wrong.

I know it isn't best practise to use MySQL like this, but I'm doing it for a reason.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: mysql_* functions are unsafe and deprecated. Please, use mysqli_* or PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM` instead of `SELECT FROM`

Comment: There is no error @LoganWayne

Comment: BTW: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing columns to be selected in your `SELECT` query, or you can select all by putting `*`, which means selecting all column.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ec_opps WHERE id='" . $_GET["UPDATE"]."'";
```

Your query is very prone to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

You should refrain from using MySQL. It's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) already. You should be at least using `MySQLi_*` instead.

```
<?php
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM ec_opps WHERE id=?"; /* REPLACE NEEDED COLUMN OR ADD/REMOVE COLUMNS TO BE SELECTED */

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["UPDATE"]); /* BIND GET VALUE TO THE QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($column1,$column2); /* BIND RESULTS */

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { /* FETCH RESULTS */
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $column1, $column2);
    }

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ec_opps WHERE id=" . $_GET["UPDATE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `*` in your query.

You need to use:
`SELECT * FROM` 
instead of 
`SELECT FROM`

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the query. It is missing `*`. Try with -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ec_opps WHERE id='" . $_GET["UPDATE"] . "'";
```

Please avoid using `mysql`. Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` is deprecated now.